# How to initiate workers in celery

Tags: django, celery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know if is this the correct way to initiate workers in celery:

> celery multi start -A app conc carga -c:conc 1 -c:carga 3

If anyone can give more details of what this script does, I'm trying to run async task in django using celery.

Then, I start celery doing this:

> ./manage.py celeryid -lDEBUG